# How do I differentiate between decade and century in phrases like "the late 1600s"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-requests, numbers

If I wanted to say something occurred occurred between 1627 and 1629, I would use "the late 1620s". However, if I wanted to say something occurred between 1607 and 1609, I couldn't use "the late 1600s" because that would imply it occurred between 1670 and 1699.

Comment: You can say "the early 1600s"

Comment: There didn't used to be a problem until people started using "the 1600s" to mean "the 17th century". Then "the 1600s" meant 1600-1609. The shift in usage began because a lot of people were confused and thought that the 17th century started in 1700 (yes I know it ended then, not in 1699). This change in usage isn't a bad idea but does cause a problem when talking about the first 10 (or, to some people 9) years of a century.

Answer (score 4):

There is no broadly well-understood way of expressing this unambiguously in the form you want. Some people use "aughts" to refer to the first decade of a century, as in "late sixteen-aughts", but I suspect that would be harder to parse for most people than just rephrasing as "occurred between 1605 and 1610". This is just a gap in the language.

Answer (score 3):

Using "1600s" for the decade would stop the average reader in their tracks; I would interpret it as referring to the century. To clarify, a writer could take a few approaches:

**1. Using parentheses**
Using parentheses or other means, one might specify without being too explicit.

> The "aughts" is one way of referring to the first decade of a century, in American English, such as 2000s *(decade)*.
> — [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aughts) (emphasis mine)

You could apply this as follows.

> One of the first historic moments of *the 1800s (the decade)* was President John Adams moving into an unfinished White House.

**2. Using a relatively new word**
In appropriate context, you could use one of the newer words for "first decade of a century":

- [The aughts](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/aughts)
- [The noughties](https://web.archive.org/web/20140512230010/http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/special_report/1999/02/99/e-cyclopedia/585224.stm)
- [The oughties](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/oughties), etc.

For example, one may write,

> #### The 1800s in U.S. Politics
>
> - President John Adams moved into the White House in *the aughts*.

These have an informal ring to them. We have only relatively recently started using these[⁵](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aughts%2Cnoughties%2Coughties&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caughts%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnoughties%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coughties%3B%2Cc0), so they are discontinuous in regional popularity.

**3. Being explicit**
In my view, this extract states the **best practice** in this case, which I, as a reader, find concise enough.

> When writing about the first two decades of a century, it’s probably best to be a little wordy for the sake of clarity. For example:
>
> > History seemed to repeat itself in *the decade 2000–2009*.
>
> — [Daily Writing Tips](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/writing-the-century/) (emphasis mine)

Some might even prefer an even longer version:

> Documented here is *the first decade of the 1800's* with duels, battles, explorations, and births in the U.S. and abroad.
> — [ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/timeline-from-1800-to-1810-1774034) (emphasis mine)